# JQuery aproach to count elements before and after: always same value

Tags: cypress

I have a table with columns and below, an icon upon clicking, I can modify the table columns.
Now I want to count the columns before and after. I have a solution which works, where I call the the following before and after and then use the wrapped alias (via parseInt) to compare:

```
cy.get('body').then(($el) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
  const countColsNr = $el.find('th[e2e-tag-header]').length;
  cy.wrap(**to be named**).as(`${s}`);
});
```

This counts the actual columns and saves it in the variable **to be named**.
However, if I use a JQuery approach, it always gets the same column number, which is at the beginning of the test:

```
const beforetColsNr = Cypress.$('th[e2e-tag-header]').length;
log(beforetColsNr.toString());
    ... column handling code
    ... also tried with wait inbetween steps for debug
const afterColsNr = Cypress.$('th[e2e-tag-header]').length;
log(afterColsNr.toString());
```

Before number and after, are the same! When I look at the state of the browser (screenshot), I can see different columns amount at time of counting in after. This JQ-approach does not count properly the second time or uses the first value.

Is this something which is expected? Or is something I have to investigate?

Comment: What is interesting is: that if I do something like: expect(beforeColNr, 'Count the columns before and after'').to.be.greaterThan(afterColsNr); The runner knows already beforehand that the numbers are the same.

Comment: Try making a global object variable since referrance types are still supported in cypress - it works for me. `let globalVariablesObject = {}; //code to get the length; globalVariablesObject.lenghNeeded = lengthIFound`

Answer (score 0):

cypress is asyncrhonous, so beforetColsNr and aftterColsNr are initialized at the same moment.
In the "cypress" mode in your first code block it works because of the usage of the .then().

Comment: After playing around and reading, I can confirm this. However, that means I always have to go via these aliases.